# Link Printing two times

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am getting an error while printing content using `for each`. The values are being retrieved from three tables using foreign key. All the data from the three table are working fine like Id passing etc. The problem is in the printing data.  It was printing the same title and link two times like:

**Link name 1** Link name2 **Link name 1** Link name2

Below I have added my code:

**Connection**

```
'connect/MysqlConnect.php';
$con = MysqlConnect::getInstance();
$page = $_GET['page'];
$powerpoint=$con->select("SELECT * FROM `category`WHERE `cid` = " . MysqlConnect::dbEscape($page), false);
$powerpoint1=$con->select("select link.linkid,link.link from link inner join category on link.cid = " . MysqlConnect::dbEscape($page),true );
$powerpoint2=$con->select("select link.linkid,link.link from link inner join category on link.cid = category.cid");
```

**Link Printing code**

```
<?php foreach($powerpoint1 as $row){?>
    <a href="download.php?page=<?php echo $row['linkid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['link'];?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/g87qT.jpg

Comment: first, you should use " to encapsulate the URL, next you should be using ' for the url stuff inside to clean up the statement, like so:
<?php foreach($powerpoint1 as $row){
$linkid=$row[`linkid`];
$link=$row['link'];
echo "<a href='download.php?page=$linkid'>$link</a>";
} ?>

Comment: How is your first and third `SELECT` statements relevant to your question? What data is in the database? What data is in `$powerpoint1`?

Comment: guys, this a powerpoint downloading website. Iam not familiar with php. The code I have added above is the page showing the downloading links, image and Description area. These data's are getting from two tables we have used forinkey. when admin submit ppt or pdf file it will store in a table with a name and random link here is the link for database table screenshot. 
Category table: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ7It.jpg

Link table screenshot :http://i.stack.imgur.com/KCwye.jpg

Comment: Error solved correct code below
<?php
include 'connect/MysqlConnect.php';
$con = MysqlConnect::getInstance();
$page = $_GET['page'];
$powerpoint=$con->select("SELECT * FROM `category`WHERE `cid` = " . MysqlConnect::dbEscape($page), false);
$powerpoint1=$con->select("select link.linkid,link.link from link inner join category  ON  link.cid = category.cid AND  link.cid = " . MysqlConnect::dbEscape($page),true );
$powerpoint2=$con->select("select link.linkid,link.link from link inner join category on link.cid = category.cid");

?>